Command to mount a VHDX file from Local G: GoogleDrive folder?
I am trying to mount a VHDX file that I do have stored into my local hard-drive into a local G: Google-Drive folder and unfortunately I can't get the syntax right.
My attempt it is as follows:
@echo off
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "&{Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath 'G:\My Drive\o.vhdx'}"

If I do open PowerShell as admin and run the  Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "G:\My Drive\o.vhdx"
everything works fine, but I do need to to mount this drive by launching the command from a .bat file.
Ideally will be better if I can also unmount the mounted drive from the same .bat file if the drive it is already mounted. I am using "V:" as mounting point.
My attempt it is as follows:
@echo off
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "&{Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath 'G:\My Drive\o.vhdx'}"


You forgot to tell us what happens when you run the .bat file :)

Yes, I do specified: "I am trying to mount a VHDX file".
